# Not able to use grails database session plugin with mongodb

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

We are using grails 2.3.5 app with mongodb (no hibernate installed). I had forked & modified grails database session plugin with HQL queries to use simple queries so as to support mongodb.

Then when I'm trying to login via ajax, it fails. By fail, I mean that, session in created & persisted to the database but not able to login. When I enabled to logs, I saw cookies is present in the request path `/j_spring_security_check` after authentication but is not available after redirect i.e. in path `/login/ajaxSuccess` which causing authentication to be treated as false & a new session is created.

Our URL mapping config looks like this: (Does not matters)

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
     constraints {
     }
}

"/v2/$customController/action/$customAction" {
    controller = {
        return params.customController?.toUpperCamelCase()
    }
    action = {
        return params.customAction?.toUpperCamelCase()
    }
}

"/v2/$resource/$resourceId?/$subResource?/$subResourceId?" {
    controller = {
        if (params.subResource) {
            return params.subResource.toUpperCamelCase()
        }
        return params.resource.toUpperCamelCase()
    }
    action = {
        Map actionMethodMap = [GET: params.resourceId ? "show" : "index", POST: "save", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
        return actionMethodMap[request.method.toUpperCase()]
    }
    id = {
        if (params.subResource && params.subResourceId) {
            return params.subResourceId
        }
        return params.resourceId
    }
}
```

Our configuration looks like this for spring security:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.test.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.test.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.test.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true

//grails.plugins.springsecurity.redirectStrategy.contextRelative = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/app/ng/index.html"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = "/app/ng/index.html#/auth/signin"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl = "/v2/login/action/auth-ajax"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.encodePassword = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/j_spring_security_switch_user': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/ck/standard/filemanager':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/ck/standard/uploader':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/ck/ofm/filemanager':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/ck/ofm/filetree':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/quartz/**': ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    '/**'          : ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Other than this, `grails.serverURL` config is commented for all environments to support wildcard subdomain.

Using:

Spring Security Core plugin version 1.2.7.3
Cookie plugin version 0.51
Webxml plugin version 1.4.1
Mongodb plugin version 2.0.1

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My question is, why authentication is failing and not finding the cookie after successful authentication?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It is also not working with any rest client. So this doesn't have to do anything with angularjs.

Comment: It almost sounds like you have something configured incorrectly for the Spring Security plugin. Post your spring security config (in Config.groovy) along with what version of the plugin you are using. Also any channel definitions you have defined would be helpful as well.

Comment: Sure Joshua. I had modified the issue description with configurations. Please have a look.